# Get video size in youtube

Tags: javascript, css, youtube

I'd like to set the viewport to the video size in a youtube video. In any flash video, the `<embed>` tag's `flashvars` attribute has a detail like `adaptive_fmts=size%3D1280x720` and I need 1280 and 720 from that.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to set the viewport (called `#player-api`) to this size *purely* in CSS3? Or baring that, what is a simple javascript I could load to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

found on my own..

there is no CSS method .. none before CCS4 at least. 
one way, made easier with jQuery, is:

```
var jqs = document.createElement('script');
jqs.src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqs);
//wait until jQuery has a chance to load. then...
jQuery.noConflict();
var wh = jQuery("#player-api embed").attr("flashvars").match(/adaptive_fmts=size\%3D(.\d+)x(.\d+)/);
// now wh[1] is width and wh[2] is height
jQuery("#player-api").width(wh[1]).height(wh[2])
```

this uses javascript's `.match` on the element to return the details in an array.